# Editing bootstrap editable dialogue box(Adding X close button on the top)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, textarea, dialog

[image: my current output]});[image: result i want]

I want to add close X button in the bootstrap custom editable class. when user click on X it should act same as X button on button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a span to the right of your "Enter comments" title, and bind an onclick handler which would simply trigger the click of the "X" button below. That should do your job.

Comment: I cant access that DOM element as it is being automatically created by editable class by bootstrap

Comment: To dynamically add a button, use the class/id of the title element, and add your new "X" button as its sibling or child of its parent element, and use css to position it accordingly. Also bind an onclick event just then.